# Android generic property

Tags: java, android, ios, generics, reflection

I have on object, where one property should be possible go store generic objects. All this objects extend a basic class "BaseObject".
But there are a lot of object that extend "BaseObject" and the property should be able to store all kind of these...

In Swift(iOS) I simply define a property as "AnyObject" like this:

```
class StoreObject
{
    var object: AnyObject?
    var list: Array<AnyObject>?
}
```

In Java, I tried it with this: (short version)

```
public class StoreObject
{
    // this should store one of the objects
    public Class<? extends BaseObject> object = null;

    // this should store a list(all the same type) of the objects
    public ArrayList<? extends BaseObject> list = null;
}
```

But this is not working :(

Example:

```
StoreObject store = new StoreObject();
store.object = new TextObject; // TestObject extends BaseObject
```

And here I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: TestObject cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

Can somebody give me a hint on this?

Thanks,
Urkman

Comment: You should realize by now that "this is not working" is not an acceptable problem statement when looking for help. You need to describe *exactly how* it isn't working including any error messages if relevant.

Comment: I added some example code... It was lost, while I was editing the questing... Sorry for that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

```
public class StoreObject<T extends BaseObject> {
    public T object = null;
    // alternatively: public BaseObject object = null;
    // that will allow for object to be any subclass of BaseObject
    public ArrayList<T> list = null;
}
```

In this example, you declare a generic class which must extend `BaseObject` and then your `StoreObject` will have an object called `object` which is of type `T` (which extends `BaseObject`) and you can also have an `ArrayList` of type `T`, which means all the objects in the list must be of the same time.

You would create an instance of this class like so:

```
StoreObject<SomeClassExtendingBaseObject> store = new StoreObject<>();
```

and then that `store` object will have an object and a list of type `SomeClassExtendingBaseObject`

Answer (score -2):

A good translation of your Swift into Java would be:

```
public class StoreObject
{
    public Object object;

    public ArrayList<Object> list;
}
```

`AnyObject` is a protocol in Swift that all objects conform to, so a variable of type `AnyObject` can hold a reference to any object. In Java, `Object` is the supertype of all reference types and a variable of type `Object` can hold a reference to any object.